# How to insert div underneath list of floating divs

Tags: javascript, css

Say you have 5-20 inner boxes inside an outer box, which has a width of 300-500 pixels.

```
<outer>
<inner>Number 1</inner>
<inner>Number 2</inner>
<inner>Number 3</inner>
<inner>Number 4</inner>
<inner>Number 5</inner>
<inner>Number 6</inner>
...
</outer>
```

Depending on the outer width, they could end up being displayed like this:

```
Number 1  Number 2
Number 3  Number 4
Number 5  Number 6
```

Or this:

```
Number 1  Number 2  Number 3
Number 4  Number 5  Number 6
```

Now, when you tap an inner box (eg. #2), you want to reveal a new box underneath the tapped box:

```
Number 1  Number 2
+----------------+
|                |
| Hello Number 2 |
|                |
+----------------+
Number 3  Number 4
Number 5  Number 6
```

Or if the width is larger, it would look like this:

```
Number 1  Number 2  Number 3
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|      Hello Number 2      |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
Number 4  Number 5  Number 6
```

My question is, in order to be able to easily insert the new box in the correct place in markup, what is the best way to lay out the inner boxes?

a) Simply float the inner boxes. **Good:** Browser handles positioning. **Bad:** How do you determine where to insert the new box when your code doesn't know the positions of the inner boxes?

b) Have your code position the boxes in columns and rows according to the available width. **Good:** Easy to insert the new box the right place. **Problem:** Creates challenges with responsiveness.

[Example: See how album details are revealed in iTunes when clicking an album thumbnail](http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2012/12/albums-view-2-100017933-orig.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope i got your question right, you need to change the css when needed , for example add a class that has float:none and clear:both when a condition (like click occurs.

I did an example on fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ejeqs8m7/2/
Just click on any of the divs.

It toggles a class .clicked that looks like this:

```
.clicked {
  float:none;
  clear:both;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: No problem - change the logic inside the click handler. Instead of changing it, a new one next to it.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to give you an idea on how:[https://jsfiddle.net/ejeqs8m7/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/ejeqs8m7/3/)

Comment: Your updated example is incorrect. The inserted content should always be inserted *underneath* the clicked element, and regardless of how many divs are displayed per line.

Comment: You should always relay on floats, Otherwise it will be hard to keep it responsive. You can also play with inline-block and block displays instead of floats. If i didn't gave exactly what you need, play with it - It is good way to do it. Maybe instead of insert before the clicked div place it after or where ever you see fit.

Comment: You suggest floats: The question is, then: How do you know *specifically* where to insert the new, large div, when your code doesn't know how the browser has laid out the inner divs?

Comment: I think it is more a question of where do you want it to appear, your example shows the inserted div will take 100% of the width of the container element, and as divs are block elements by default it will always take the entire width of it's contained (if not floated), you just need to decide where to put it, before or after... I used insertBefore method but you can use any other - for example Element.insertAdjacentHTML() [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: @forthrin I would prob use CSS for layout but additionally keep track of how many columns have been rendered in JS (either by reading the position of the elements or just mirroring your css rules in JS) to help determine where to render the large div. Alternativly maybe flexbox can help here (I'm always suprised at what can be done with flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the elements are in same horizontal line or not and add the viewer element dynamically using JavaScript.

```js
var idles = document.querySelectorAll('.idle');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(idles, function(idle) {
  idle.addEventListener('click', showInfo);
});

function showInfo(e) {
  var selectedTabClass = 'active';
  var viewerClass = 'viewer';
  if (showInfo.prevClickElement && showInfo.prevClickElement !== this) {
    showInfo.prevClickElement.classList.remove(selectedTabClass);
  }
  if (this.classList.contains(selectedTabClass)) {
    // remove viewer element
    showInfo.viewer.parentElement.removeChild(showInfo.viewer);
    this.classList.remove(selectedTabClass);
    return;
  }
  if (!showInfo.viewer) {
    // Create a viewer element only if it wasn't created before
    showInfo.viewer = document.createElement('div');
    showInfo.viewer.classList.add(viewerClass);
  }

  if (!showInfo.section) {
    // Get the parent container
    showInfo.section = document.querySelector('section');
  }
  var after = this;
  // Getting the next element which isn't in the exact horizontal line with the clicked element
  while (after && after.offsetTop === this.offsetTop) {
    after = after.nextElementSibling;
  }

  // Add the content through the below line
  showInfo.viewer.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + " Viewer";
  if (after) {
    showInfo.section.insertBefore(showInfo.viewer, after);
  } else {
    // if after element isn't present then safely assuming that the clicked element was in the last horizontal line and appending the viewer element
    showInfo.section.appendChild(showInfo.viewer);
  }
  this.classList.add(selectedTabClass);
  showInfo.prevClickElement = this;
}
```

```css
section {
  width: 200px;
}
.idle {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
.clicked {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: auto;
}
.viewer {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="idle">Div #1</div>
  <div class="idle">Div #2</div>
  <div class="idle">Div #3</div>
  <div class="idle">Div #4</div>
  <div class="idle">Div #5</div>
  <div class="idle">Div #6</div>
  <div class="idle">Div #7</div>
  <div class="idle">Div #8</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You basically suggest to check the vertical position of the inner boxes relative to the outer box. This is actually quite a good approach. Best so far, at least!

Comment: @forthrin you can also do in many ways but I find this approach to have lesser code. :)